# Having trouble rendering Javascript in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Here's the relevant controller code:

```
if @song.update_attributes(params[:song])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {
      render :action => 'success'
    }
  end
else
```

Here's what's in `success.js.erb`:

```
$("#song_updated_at").val( "<%= escape_javascript @song.updated_at %>" )
```

Here's the error I get:

```
ActionView::TemplateError ($_ value need to be String (nil given)) on line #1 of app/views/songs/success.js.erb:
1: $("#song_updated_at").val( "<%= escape_javascript @song.updated_at %>" )

    app/views/songs/success.js.erb:1
    app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:52:in `update'
    app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:50:in `update'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `to_s` your `updated_at`, because `escape_javascript` expects a String. `updated_at` returns a `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ARGGHHHHH! `escape_javascript` should take care of this automatically!

Comment: I agree, I don't understand why it doesn't.